# Microsoft Azure - Gulp 3.8.10 does not work on fresh Web App instance

Tags: azure, npm, gulp, kudu

I am using a fresh instance of a Web App with Node 12.3 and NPM 2.9.1. Gulp PATH appears to be set to D:\Program Files (x86)\gulp\3.8.10. I believe Gulp 3.8.10 has a bug that should be fixed with an update to 3.8.11. I am unable to use gulp until this is worked out... Unless there is another way to handle this? Any help from the Azure team would be appreciated. Deploying with Gulp has been a thorn in my side on this platform. I am trying to use vNext deployment with Angular and WebApi... My gulp CI builds can't move forward because of this. Thanks for anyone able to help!

I think this issue is noted here https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/893

```
Kudu Remote Execution Console
Type 'exit' then hit 'enter' to get a new CMD process.
Type 'cls' to clear the console

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\home>gulp -v
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Program Files (x86)\gulp\3.8.10\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags\3.28.73.flags.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\gulp\3.8.10\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:25:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short version:**

You can install your own version of gulp where ever you have access, say `D:\home\npm_tools\` for example, then override the default gulp path by setting an AppSetting `GULP_PATH = D:\home\npm_tools\`

**The long version:**

1) Go the DebugConsole above

2) `npm config set prefix "D:\home\npm_tools"` (or where ever you want it to be)

3) `npm install -g gulp`  (or you can really zip up the folder from your machine and drop it somewhere if your machine is also running windows)

4) Go to portal or where you manage you app settings and set `GULP_PATH = D:\home\npm_tools\`

5) Refresh the DebugConsole

6) `gulp -v`, you should get `3.9.0` if you've just install the latest at the time of writing this comment

I realize this is a bit hacky and manual, but it should get you unblocked until we update that gulp version

Comment: Thank you! I guess the real trick here is setting: 
`GULP_PATH = D:\home\npm_tools`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested `gulp -v` on a fresh Azure Web App. Gulp is present. Since you're experiencing a difficulty, you could try installing it.

1. Go to `your-domain.scm.azurewebsites.net`
2. Choose Debug console > CMD
3. Run `npm install gulp`
4. Test with `gulp -v`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I had done that and also tried npm install gulp -g. The same error is still thrown. Can you verify you have the latest NPM settings for that instance? I noted that I am using Node 12.3 and NPM 2.9.1.

Comment: The `npm` version is `1.4.28` and the `node` one is `v0.10.32`. This is from running `npm -v` and `node -v` from the debug console.

Comment: This problem appears to be specific to newer Node versions 0.12.0 and higher. The latest version of Gulp fixes this but I am unable to install myself as this folder (D:\Program Files (x86)\gulp) appears to be a special folder manager by Azure.